# when calling method from another class - retuns an incomprehensible value JAVA

Tags: java, class, methods

When i run 2nd class i see " Car@15ab7626 " why ? in teory i must see 20, yes?
I have alredy used differnet combinatoin & ask google but dont understent why.

i have 1 class

```
public class Car {  
    public int drive(int a) { 
        int distance = 2*a;
        return distance;  
    }
}
```

and 2nd class

```
public class CarOwner { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car a = new Car();
        a.drive(10);
        System.out.println(a);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at [this stackoverflow topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659515/overriding-tostring-method)

Answer (score 5):

**You are printing the car object, not the result printed by drive**

That  **incomprehensible value JAVA** is textual representation of Object.

When you do `System.out.println(a);` then by default `toString()` method calls on passed `object.`

As per docs of [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)()

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object.

So

`Car@15ab7626`  is the textual representation of Values class.

To print result which is returned by your `drive()` method, print,

```
 System.out.println(a.drive(10));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to print the result from the `drive()` method, assign the result to a variable and then print it.

```
int result = a.drive(10);
System.out.println("Result = " + result);
```

or directly pass the result to the `System.out.println()` method;

```
System.out.println("Result = " + a.drive(10));
```

If you want to print the `a` object in a readable way, override the `toString()` method in the `Car` class definition.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return "This is a car"; //for example
}
```

Comment: why is assigning to a variable needed?

Comment: For clarification. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the value you have from a drive method, but you're not printing it.

To print out the value of the drive method, use

```
public class CarOwner {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Car a = new Car();
     System.out.println(a.drive(10));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not the way method return values work. If you want to see the result as 20, replace your SOP with the following

```
 System.out.println(a.drive(10));
```