# How do we loop Java object

Tags: java

Below is the output of my code...

```
System.out.println(CompanyStructure.get());

 Output:    [com.some.spf.b2bac.facilit.api.parameter.GetkingResult$king@2357662d, com.some.spf.b2bac.facilit.api.parameter.GetkingResult$king@633ced71, com.some.spf.b2bac.facilit.api.parameter.GetkingResult$king@312aac03]
```

I tried to convert to json string.

```
jsonString = CommonUtil.convertFromEntityToJsonStr(CompanyStructure.get());

System.out.println(jsonString);

Output:[{"customerId":"1"},{"customerId":"2"},{"customerId":"3"}];
```

I want to fetch all `names` with the ids `1,2,3` through sql iam using postgresql. how do i fix this?

Comment: Are you talking about overriding `toString`?

Comment: Yes,Thats what i meant... sorry Iam new to java

Comment: if you are new to Java, you should start at the beginning, not start with utils, converters, Json, ...

Comment: ya you are right... but my company has given this project... no option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the Object representation of object. To loop though the objects that `get()` method use a for each:

```
for (GetkingResult result : CompanyStructure.get()) {
    if (result.getId() == 1) // do something
}
```

Also you [can override the `toString()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659515/overriding-tostring-method) of the `GetkingResult` object.